# Removing Postgresql as dependency while software packaging

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, ubuntu, software-packaging

I have written a code in **Python** that I want to turn into a Ubuntu PPA so that everyone can download it and use it.

For storing data, I used **postgresql** rather than files as it provides me a structure of the table.

Now if I turn my code into a package, I guess I need to make postgresql as a dependency ( still not sure about it but most probably ). If yes, I don't want to do that because my application is really small and I don't want the person installing my software, installing postgresql which he doesnt use.

So my question is there anyway I can avoid postgresql as a dependency. May be any other db tool which is default for Ubuntu or storing it in system and accessing it.

All the views are welcome. :)

Thank u.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a use case for [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org).

It embeds a little database engine into your application and writes to a file. You might want to read the page [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) first to be sure if this fits your needs.

For Python2 there is a library [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Hi snoreven. Thanx for the reply. But even to use SQLite, user would have to install it. Right? But thanx it's still a cheaper alternative to postgresql.

Comment: This is likely correct (I don't know if it is in the Ubuntu default system). But it is small and there is a *very high* chance of it already being installed. SQLite is used in a lot of programs and no one will care about it being required.

Comment: Actually I don't have it installed in my ubuntu. But yes surely it's a light package and if don't get any other solution I can use this. Thank you.